# How to remove protective film from shower after being left in the sun

Tags: removal

How to remove protective film from shower after being baked in the sun

Answer (score 1):

No doubt the adhesive (and maybe the sheeting itself) has permanently hardened at room temperature. You'll need to either warm it or use a solvent to soften the adhesive.

First, I'd try a heat lamp. An infrared flood light would do, or a halogen utility light in a pinch. Set it up so that it's no closer than maybe 24" from the tub at any point--you don't want to scorch the surface. Monitor it closely and often. Work one area at a time.

If that doesn't work, move to mild solvents like GooGone, depending on what the manufacturer says about cleaning solutions.

Comment: You can also use a heat gun. You just want to avoid heating up an area too quickly because you can ruin the finish of the tub. A heat setting of around 300 degrees F should do the job.